# Add next button showing more details of a specific record using PDO

Tags: php, pdo

I'm currently working on a project,the CRUD function is working fine and i'm nearly finished but there's only one problem that can't figure it on how to do it.my problem is that, i have an update button and the update function works fine when i clicked the update button it will a specific record that i chose my problem is that i want to add a next button so that when i clicked on the nejxt button it will show other details on that person.because in my project there are lot of details to be included so i need a next button so i can view the other details of that specific record that i chose..can somebody please help me with it?

here is my code

**class.user.php**

```
public function dataview($query)
{

$stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * from login ORDER BY username");
$stmt->execute();

if($stmt->rowCount()>0)
{
    while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td> ".$row['user_id']." </td>";
        echo "<td> ".$row['username']." </td>";

        echo '<td><a target="_blank" onclick="pop_up(this)" href=VIEWSAMPLE.PHP?user_id='.$row['user_id'].'>'.$row["username"].'</a></td>';

        echo "<td> ".$row['password']." </td>";
        echo '<td><a style="float:left" target="_blank" href="update.php?user_id=' .  $row["user_id"] . '>'.$row["username"].'"<input name="image" type="image" value="edit" onclick="pop_up(this)"><image src="image/EDIT.png" class="img-responsive" width="25px"></a>
        <a style="float:left" href="delete.php?user_id=' . $row["user_id"] . '>"<input name="image" type="image" value="delete" onclick="return confirm(\'are you sure?\')"><image src="image/DELETE.png" class="img-responsive" width="25px"> </a></td>';
        echo "</tr>";
    }
}
else
{
    echo "<tr>";
        "<td>Nothing here...</td>";
        "</tr>";
}
}
}
```

**and here is my viewsample.php where i want to add a next button**

```
 <?php
 include_once 'dbconfig.php';
 $username = isset($_GET['username']) ? $_GET['username'] : '';
 $password = isset($_GET['password']) ? $_GET['password'] : '';
 $province = isset($_GET['province']) ? $_GET['province'] : '';

 if(isset($_GET['user_id']))
 {
     $user_id = $_GET['user_id'];
     extract($crud->getID($user_id));
 }
 ?>

 <body>

 <button onclick="this.style.display='none';document.body.offsetHeight;window.print();this.style.display='inline';">Print</button>

 <br />
 <br />

 <div id="Survey-view">
    <div id="header">
    </div>

 <p><strong>INFORMATION</strong></p>
        <hr />
            <div id="main-frame">
                <table id="information-content" cellspacing="0">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Username</th>
                            <th>Password</th>
                            <th>Province</th>
                        </tr>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $username; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $password; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $province; ?></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                    </thead>
                </table>
            </div>
        <br />
    <br />
```

Comment: get the id from database call edit page with that id.

Comment: what is the url for edit page??

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju as you can see in my viewsample.php

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju i just want to add something like this in my viesample.php so when i cleck this it will redirect me to next.php where the other details of that record is available <a href="next.php">EDIT</a>

Comment: no need to create one more file, check the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In query, fetch next id from database.

then in `viewsample.php` file add following code.

```
<a href="viewsample.php?user_id=id from database">Next</a>
```

and in `viewsample.php`, get data based on id passed in `$_GET['user_id']`

use this query to fetch next id,

```
select * from table where id = (select min(id) from table where id > current id)
```

Comment: You should probably mention that the `$_GET` data should be sanitized.

Comment: where i'm supposed to put this select * from table where id = (select min(id) from table where id > current id) and why next id?

Comment: iwant to view only one record because theres a lot of details in that record i need to do some next button..i dont the next button to go to the id

Comment: you shud execute that where you are fetching data for current user.

Comment: you will get user id. so based on that, add it to next button.